# checkbox onclick in php function

Tags: php, checkbox

Can i write some code to execute while my check box is checked in my php code..

my declaration of check box is...

```
<input id="checkbox" name="click" type="checkbox" onclick="check(this)"/>
```

i thought to perform a function called `check()` while clicking the check box..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function check(cb)
  {
      if($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"")
      {
        //my functionality and operations
      }
  }
```

But its not working, how can i perform the onclick event in the Checkbox's action..

Comment: Onclick happens in the browser, PHP runs on the server. You need to use AJAX if you want the onclick function to interact with the server.

Comment: You're passing the reference in the html itself, so why not just use it? Why not access cb in your JavaScript?

Comment: What's the PHP function you mentioned?

Comment: I think he/she wants to execute some php code when the checkbox is checked. Is this correct @GowthAMI?

Comment: yes, a particular code need to execute..

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's a mistake. It should be `.is(":checked")`.

```
function check(cb)
{
    if($(cb).is(":checked"))
    {
        //my functionality and operations
    }
}
```

And the HTML should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="check(this);" />
```

---

Or, if you wanna invoke a PHP Function after clicking on Checkbox, you need to write an AJAX code. If this is the case, in your `if` condition, and checked condition, you can call a PHP file, that calls only this function.

```
function check(cb)
{
    if($(cb).is(":checked"))
    {
        $.getScript("clickCheckbox.php");
    }
}
```

And you can write JavaScript plus PHP in the `clickCheckbox.php` file, say something like this:

#### `clickCheckbox.php`

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    unlink("delete.png");
    echo 'alert("Deleted!");';
?>
```

Once you click on the checkbox, and if the state is `checked`, it gives out an AJAX call to this PHP file, where you are deleting a file `delete.png` and in the `echo` statement, you are outputting a JavaScript alert, so that you will get an alert message saying `Deleted!`.

Comment: You don't use `cb`! you can just write `if (cb.checked)` or if you really want to use jquery `if ($(cb).is(":checked"))`

Comment: @Sanchit My mistake. Didn't notice. Updated. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myform :checkbox').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        // the checkbox was checked 
    } else {
        // the checkbox was unchecked
    }
});
```

Where your form has id `myform`

Comment: -1 So if you click ANY checkbox in the form with id myForm this code will run. That really doesn't look like what the original user was trying to do. Moreover the question is unclear because the poster mentions the word php.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

or inside an event

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(){

 if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    //your routine here if checked
 }else{
    //routine here if not checked
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put like this:
Include the column `checked` in your table with default value NO.
Then after your SELECT statement show the array.

page1.php

```
<input type=checkbox value="<?php $row['checked']?>" onclick="location.href = 'update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&checked=<?php if ($row['checked'] == 'YES') {  ?>NO<?php } else {?>YES<?php } ?>';" <?php if ($row['checked'] == 'YES') {  ?> checked <?php } ?>>
```

update.php

```
<?php  include('server.php'); ?>
<?php


$id = $_GET['id'];
$checked = $_GET['checked'];
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    
    
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET
    
                checked     = '$checked' 
                WHERE `id` = '$id' ";



    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    header('location: page1.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<input id="checkbox" name="click" type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>

//in js
if( $('input[name=checkbox]').is(':checked') ){
   // your code
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[name=click]`?

Comment: -1 So if you click ANY checkbox with the name `checkbox`, anywhere on the page this code will run. That really doesn't look like what the original user was trying to do. Moreover the question is unclear because the poster mentions the word php.

Comment: then you use with id like 
if( $('#checkbox').is(':checked') ){
   // your code
}